# restrict_access using tokens in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm generating a token to restrict access to certain post for certain people. Everything's working fine but it's allowing anyone with a token to look at any post instead of the post the that they're allowed to view only. **For an example, if a token was generated for post/1 & post/1 only, the user can still visit post/2 using the same token. How do I fix this?**

Here's my post controller

```
before_filter :restrict_access, only: [:show]
```

Here's my *private restrict_access method* in my posts controller

```
def restrict_access
  link_token = LinkToken.find_by_token(params[:token])
  head :unauthorized unless link_token
end
```

Thanks in advance

Getting "Couldn't find Post without an ID"

```
def restrict_access
  post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  link_token = LinkToken.find_by_token(params[:token])
  head :unauthorized unless link_token
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only check if the token exists, it doesn't matter which token is entered. 
I suppose in your `LinkToken` model the post is kept as a foreign key, overwise you won't be able to fix it.

When yes, try something like this <del>(find_by_x helpers are deprecated as of Rails 4)</del> *they return a single resource*:

`link_token = LinkToken.where(post_id: params[:id], token: params[:token]).first`

Comment: This is actually false, `find_by_x` are the only dynamic finders that *aren't* being deprecated:  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations  Excerpt reads "All dynamic methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated. Here's how you can rewrite the code:"

Comment: I'm getting "Couldn't find Post without an ID".. I edited in how I'm trying to get it in my original question @s.krueger

Comment: Is there any way for me to save the post_id when creating it? Right now I have `@token = LinkToken.create`

Comment: I fixed the post_id thing. I'll check back if I get this thing working

Comment: Turns out there was a routing typo so this works perfectly. Thanks @Pedro